# Help With Error C#: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property RpgTutorial.Character.Swordsmanship

Tags: c#-4.0

I am very new to C# and programming in general and I'm having the error (described in the title box) when I run this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RpgTutorial
{
    public class HeroSkills : Character
    {
        public int Skill()    
        {
            if (Hero.Swordsmanship = 10)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I know I need to create a reference to Swordsmanship, but how exactly would I do that? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to access the `Swordsmanship` property of the same object that the method would be called for, then you can access it via the `this` reference:

```
if (this.Swordsmanship == 10) 
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a `Hero` a subclass of `Character` (or the other way around)?  If so, you can reference the property `Swordsmanship` like this:

```
if (this.Swordsmanship == 10) 
{
   ...
}
```

Otherwise if you are finding yourself needing to reference a 'hero', you can add a constructor (and property) to your `HeroSkills` class like this:

```
public HeroSkills : Character
{
   public Hero CurrentHero 
   {
      get;
      set;
   }

   public HeroSkills(Hero hero)
   {
      this.CurrentHero = hero;
   }
   ...
```

Note that the `this` keyword is not required, but signifies that the property you are accessing is a member of your class.  This can help you in readability later on.  You can then reference the `CurrentHero` around your class in your various methods like the `Skill()` as so:

```
if (this.CurrentHero.Swordsmanship == 10) 
{
   ...
}
```

You would use your newly modified class elsewhere in code like this:

```
Hero player1 = //some hero variable
var skills = new HeroSkills(player1);
int currentSkill = skills.Skill();
```